# How To Unit Test an @IBAction with asyncronous call

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, xcode7, xctest

In the following code, I want to test whether "DisplayHelper.displayAlert" has been called.  I am dependency-injecting `DisplayHelper` and `AuthService` mock objects, and using `PromiseKit`

In My ViewController:

```
@IBAction func submitButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    AuthService.updateUser(["zipcode": self.zipcodeTextField.text!])
        .then { user -> Void in
             // sucess code
        }.error { error -> Void in
            self.DisplayHelper.displayAlert("Zipcode Not Found", message: "We can't find that zipcode... please try again.", callingViewController: self)
        }
}
```

Here are the not-working tests:

```
func testSubmitButtonServerCantFindZipcode() {
    vc.zipcodeTextField.text = "00000"
    vc.submitButtonPressed(self)

    // called AuthService    (passes)
    XCTAssertEqual(authServiceMock.updateUserCalled, true)

    // called displayAlert (fails because tests run before DisplayAlert is called)
    XCTAssertEqual(displayHelperMock.displayAlertCalled, true)
}
```

How do I get the tests to wait for all of the code to execute before the assertions?

Answer (score 2):

When testing asynchronous code with XCTest you need to use [`XCTestExpectation`](http://nshipster.com/xctestcase/).

You can rewrite the test code like this:

```
let e = expectationWithDescription("display alert")
waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(3) { error in
    XCTAssertEqual(displayHelperMock.displayAlertCalled, true)
}
```

Now the only missing piece to make the test work is finding a place where to call `expectation.fulfill()`. The most appropriate place would be in your `AuthService` mock, **after** the success and failure callbacks are run.

If I can suggest you something though, writing tests that asser whether certain methods have been called is not a safe approach to testing, as you are just testing implementation rather than behaviour.

What could be a better approach is to test the two componets independently. Test`AuthService` making sure that both the success and failure path execute as expected, and the `DisplayHelper` to make sure that the alert view is actually added to the view hierarchy.

[This article](http://qualitycoding.org/testing-uialertcontrollers/) could be a useful place to start to find out how unit test alerts, and [this post](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/blog/2014/test-isolation-is-about-avoiding-mocks) is a good read on why and how to avoid mocks.

Comment: Thanks for checking this out... Sounds like a good place to start, but I'm hesitant to embed the expectation in the mocks because it requires knowledge of the internal workings of the method -- `e.fulfill()` would have to be placed just after the very last asynchronous call, so  adding another async method or changing the order of calls would break the test. Is there any way to wait for all the test code to execute?  Thanks again!